# Scala assumes wrong type when using foldLeft

Tags: scala, syntax, reduce, fold

I am trying to create a cross product function in Scala, where `k` is the number of times I build the cross product.

```
val l = List(List(1), List(2), List(3))
(1 to k).foldLeft[List[List[Int]]](l) { (acc: List[List[Int]], _) =>
    for (x <- acc; y <- l)
        yield x ::: l
}
```

However, this code does not compile:

```
test.scala:9: error: type mismatch;
    found   : List[List[Any]]
    required: List[List[Int]]
    for (x <- acc; y <- l)
           ^
```

Why does it ever think I have a `List[Any]`'s there? Clearly everything I am dealing with is `List`s of `Int`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for comprehension is effectively yielding List[List[Int or List[Int]]] hence the inferred type is List[List[Any]]. Here's an example from the repl:

```
scala> val l = List(List(1), List(2), List(3))
l: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3))
val x = for {
     |     x <- l
     |     y <- l
     |   } yield x ::: l
x: List[List[Any]] = List(List(1, List(1), List(2), List(3)), List(1, List(1), List(2), List(3)), List(1, List(1), List(2), List(3)), List(2, List(1), List(2), List(3)), List(2, List(1), List(2), List(3)), List(2, List(1), List(2), List(3)), List(3, List(1), List(2), List(3)), List(3, List(1), List(2), List(3)), List(3, List(1), List(2), List(3)))
```

Comment: Argh! This is just a typo :(, and I was looking an hour at this. Sorry for wasting your time!