# Scala fold over String results in "type mismatch; found: Any"

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm playing around with folds in Scala and, for whatever reason, ended up trying to test whether a String contains only unique characters by doing the following:

```
str
  .fold(""){ (x, y) => if (!(x contains y)) x + y else x }
  .size == str.size
```

This results in the error

```
error: type mismatch;
found: Any
required: String
```

apparently pointing to the value of `y`.

Can anyone provide insight into this?

I wouldn't have expected this behavior, and the closest answer I could find with respect to this was ["Scala assumes wrong type when using foldLeft,"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007738/scala-assumes-wrong-type-when-using-foldleft) which is similar, but doesn't quite clarify things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `foldLeft` instead of `fold`:

```
str
  .foldLeft(""){ (x, y) => if (!(x contains y)) x + y else x }
  .size == str.size
```

the signature for `fold` is:

```
fold[A1 >: Char](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

So `fold` expects the element type to be a lower bound on the accumulator type. The element type is `Char` in the case of `String`, so the possible types for `A1` are `Char`, `AnyVal` and `Any`. You pass a `String` so `Any` is the only common type, which means `x` and `y` have type `Any`, which does not have a `contains` method.

You need to the accumulator type to be different from the element type so you need to use `foldLeft`.

Comment: And the rationale is: `fold` is designed for parallel-computation, so it only works when you can combine two list elements starting anywhere in the list, e.g., in the middle.  This requires that the function be associative, and that it doesn't need to be provided a base-case-value.

On the other hand, `foldleft` and `foldright` are more general (your accumulated value can be a different type than the items in the list -- e.g. summing the *length* of all strings in a list), and works w/ non-associative functions (but not parallel-izable).